# "Content-Type" and "Content-Encoding" headers in axios

Tags: axios

I am using axios@0.21.1 and I want to validate the response headers.
I am unable validate the headers "Content-Type" and "Content-Encoding" from a GET response.

1. **"Content-Type"**: No matter what content-type i pass in request, the content-type in response is always application/JSON.
   Example Code Snippet:

- 

```
if (<token is present>) {
   request.headers = {
     authorization : 'Bearer ${token}'
   }
} else {
  config.auth =  {}
}
config.headers = Object.assign(config.header, {
                                'content-type': application/<custom content>,
                                'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
                              }
await axios.get(endPoint, config)
  .then(response => {
           return response
     }*
```

When i am checking response.header, i see that content-type is showing as "application/json" instead of the custom type. But when i hit the same url in POSTMAN i could see that content-type is as expected.

2. **Content-Encoding**: I want to validate the content-encoding in the response, but what i learnt is axios does not return content-encoding header in the response and when i check their github, they are asking to use axios.interceptors. I tried using interceptors but still i am not seeing the header in response. But this header is present in response when i try in POSTMAN. There have been some solution say CORS needs to be enabled in server side. I am strictly asking it from QA point of view because we cannot enable CORS in server side.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
axios.post(your-url, {
    headers: {
       'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
    }
})
```

or

```
axios.post(your-url, {
    headers: {
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
    }
})
```

Comment: Passing "Content-Encoding" in header wont help because i think it is a Response Header and not a Request Header. I am already passing "Accept-Encoding" as an header, but it did not help.

Comment: I think you have to set response header on backend for that request.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

I also ran into this and couldn't find a solution. Ended up using node-fetch instead.